# cuda Thrust how to get the values associated to key

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I got a list of values/keys in one side and in the other side i got a list of keys.

I want to get the values associated at this list of keys in a list.

here my pseudocode

I don't know how to make my predicate and by the way if it's the good way to reach my goal.

```
void pseudoCode()
{
    const int N = 7;
    thrust::device_vector<vec3> keys1(N);

    values[0] = vec3(1.01,1.01,1.0156); 
    values[1] = vec3(1.01,1.01,1.01561);
    values[2] = vec3(1.02,1.52,1.02); 
    values[3] = vec3(1.02,1.52,1.02); 
    values[4] = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0); 
    values[5] = vec3(5.0,1.0,1.0); 
    values[6] = vec3(5.0,1.5,1.0); 
  
    thrust::device_vector<long> values(N);
    keys1[0] = 0; 
    keys1[1] = 1;
    keys1[2] = 2;
    keys1[3] = 5;
    keys1[4] = 9;
    keys1[5] = 19;
    keys1[6] = 22;

    thrust::device_vector<long> to_find(6);
    to_find[0] = 1; 
    to_find[1] = 5;
    to_find[2] = 9;
    
    thrust::device_vector<vec3> output(6);

    auto begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(keys1.begin(), values.begin()));
    auto end = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(keys1.end(), values.end()));


    thrust::copy_if(begin, end, output, pred(to_find));

    // result 

    output[0]=values[1];
    output[1]=values[3];
    output[2]=values[4];
    

}
```

I try to make my predicate here is my code

```
struct FindValue
{
    thrust::device_vector<long>  ToFind;
    explicit FindValue(thrust::device_vector<long> toFind) : ToFind{toFind} {}

    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(thrust::tuple<vec3, long> x)
    {
        long v = thrust::get<1>(x);
        size_t N = ToFind.size(); 
        for (size_t index=0; index<N; index++)
        {
            if (v==ToFind[index]) return true;
        }   
        return false;
    }
};
```

and change the call of copy_if

```
thrust::copy_if(begin, end, output, FindValue(to_find));
```

but i got the errors

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/copy_if.inl(75): error: class "thrust::iterator_system<thrust::device_vector<vec3, thrust::device_allocator<vec3>>>" has no member "type"
          detected during instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::copy_if(InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator, Predicate) [with InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<vec3>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<long>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, OutputIterator=thrust::device_vector<vec3, thrust::device_allocator<vec3>>, Predicate=FindValue]" 
cpp_addin_new2.cu(768): here

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/copy_if.inl(80): error: no instance of overloaded function "select_system" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (System1, System2)
          detected during instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::copy_if(InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator, Predicate) [with InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<vec3>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<long>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, OutputIterator=thrust::device_vector<vec3, thrust::device_allocator<vec3>>, Predicate=FindValue]" 
cpp_addin_new2.cu(768): here

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/copy_if.inl(80): error: no instance of overloaded function "thrust::copy_if" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (<error-type>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<vec3>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<long>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<vec3>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<long>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::device_vector<vec3, thrust::device_allocator<vec3>>, FindValue)
          detected during instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::copy_if(InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator, Predicate) [with InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<vec3>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<long>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, OutputIterator=thrust::device_vector<vec3, thrust::device_allocator<vec3>>, Predicate=FindValue]" 
cpp_addin_new2.cu(768): here

3 errors detected in the compilation of "cpp_addin_new2.cu".
```

Comment: Your predicate could perform a binary search for the key in `to_find`

Comment: I effectively try to do this but don't manage to do it. with a pred

Comment: Could you show your current predicate, which does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your current approach is that `thrust::device_vector` cannot be used in device code. The functor needs to store pointer and size instead.
There are also issues with datatypes, for example, you have `long` values, and want to copy values, but the output vector contains `vec3` i.e. keys. The current functor also searches to_find for values instead of keys.

Anyways, a correct functor which searches for keys could look like this.

```
template<class KeyType>
struct CopyIfPred{
    int numToFind;
    KeyType* to_find;

    __host__ __device__
    CopyIfPred(KeyType* to_find_, int numToFind_) : numToFind(numToFind_), to_find(to_find_){}

    template<class Tup>
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const Tup& tup) const noexcept{
        const auto key = thrust::get<0>(tup);
        const bool found = thrust::binary_search(
            thrust::seq, 
            to_find, 
            to_find + numToFind, 
            key);
        return found;
    }
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
        auto begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
            keys1.begin(), 
            values.begin()
        ));
        auto end = begin + N;
        auto outputbegin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
            thrust::make_discard_iterator(), // discard copied keys
            output.begin()
        ));

        CopyIfPred<KeyType> pred(
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(to_find.data()), 
            to_find.size());


        auto endIters = thrust::copy_if(begin, end, outputbegin, pred);
        std::size_t outputsize = thrust::distance(outputbegin, endIters);

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < outputsize; i++){
            std::cout << output[i] << "\n";
        }
```

Comment: whats a beautiful solution. work fine. Thank you@Abator Abetor

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what `thrust::lower_bound` was designed to do. Just look at the example code here.

https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__vectorized__binary__search_ga04b5a67cd0daf7be4b35c2bc75d22bee.html

Comment: Please don’t post link only answers. If that link dies, your answer becomes useless